# Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql

I am getting an error with displaying the value:

```
$thedate = $row2['date'];
echo $thedate;
```

In php, which is a value from the database ($thedate) is "2015-05-05 21:52:31.000"

How can I format it to be able to display it on the php page as a string? Currently it shows error "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, so you have to use [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to format your output, e.g.

```
echo $thedate->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: @user3342443 You're welcome! (FYI: You can take a little tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works and where everything is)

Comment: @Rizier123 [I gave the OP a polite nudge earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747263/jquery-submit-does-not-work-after-ajax-pagination?noredirect=1#comment76475545_44747263) but they deleted [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44747263/1415724) and decided to [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44750977/) instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Reposting the same question is not how Stack Overflow works. But sadly you can't do much other than writing a comment.

Comment: @Rizier123 *"Cest la vie!"* I guess. OP seems to think that marking questions as solved isn't important. I'm guessing that the system that was put together to make and keep it the success it is, doesn't apply to them. Oh but I could be wrong about this; I'd hate to put words in their mouth, now that wouldn't be right ;-)

Comment: Marked as solved now I believe? Sorry I don't use this much so wasn't aware of this. I'll look at the site tour for future reference.